# Toggle two classes on one element while not toggling a sibling element

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my document, I have two elements. The contents of those elements are hidden upon loading. When a user clicks the title or the plus symbol of that element it displays the contents. At the moment, when an element is displaying the contents, if a user click anywhere in the document, it closes what ever element that's open. I don't know what's causing that problem.

Here's my javascript:

```
function DropDown(element){
    this.title = element;
    this.initEvents();
}

DropDown.prototype = {
    initEvents : function() {
        var obj = this;
        obj.title.on('click', function(event){
        $(this).parent().next('.drop').toggleClass('active');
          event.stopPropagation();
        });
      }
    }

$(function(){
    var title = new DropDown( $('.title'));
    $(document).click(function(){
        $('.drop').removeClass('active');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $rotated = false;
    $('.plus, .title').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('rotateOn'); //rotates plus symbol in CSS
    });
});
```

What this doesn't do (that I would like it to do) is if the user clicks on either the title or the plus, the contents will be displayed, and the plus symbol will be rotated.

Here's my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8sbmbcyj/) for reference. For some reason in my fiddle, the plus doesn't rotate, but in my full document that I'm working with, it does.

Comment: Why do you use two DOM ready functions `$(function(){` and `$(document).ready(function() {` ? Also the `$rotated ` usually means it's and jQuery Element reference, while you use it as boolean... Also that variable `$rotated` is not instantiated as `var` (but global)

Comment: I guess I shouldn't and just cover them in one, but does that have something to do with the problem?

Comment: no, it was offtopic sorry

Comment: Should I declare `$rotated` as a variable within the scope?

Comment: @EugeneRoss What's `$rotated` for anyhow? Your animation is a CSS class `.rotateOn`. Btw, check my answer, I think it works as you wanted.

Comment: @zer00ne Not sure what I was doing, but I see how it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem, I commented the wrong line:

```
$(function() {
  var title = new DropDown($('.title'));
  $(document).click(function() {
    //$('.drop').removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

For the span rotate add this to your css:

```js
span.rotate{
  -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
}
```

And change a bit your function:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $rotated = false;
  $('.plus, .title').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('rotateOn');
    $(this).children('span').toggleClass('rotate');
  });
});
```

Of course the + sign alone does not work but if you use for instance a string like +aaa you can see.

The full snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  function DropDown(element) {
    this.title = element;
    this.initEvents();
  }

  DropDown.prototype = {
    initEvents: function() {
      var obj = this;
      obj.title.on('click', function(event) {
        $(this).parent().next('.drop').toggleClass('active');
        event.stopPropagation();
      });
    }
  }

  $(function() {
    var title = new DropDown($('.title'));
    $(document).click(function() {
      //$('.drop').removeClass('active');
    });
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $rotated = false;
    $('.plus, .title').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('rotateOn');
      $(this).children('span').toggleClass('rotate');
    });
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #141516;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 2.3rem;
  color: #b3b3b3
}

::selection {
  background: #00DE6F;
  color: #141516
}

a {
  color: inherit
}

a:hover {
  color: inherit
}

.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.main {
  margin: 0px
}

.main a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out
}

.main a:hover {
  color: #00DC73
}

.job {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #191919;
  padding-bottom: 15px
}

.job .drop {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 20px
}

.job .drop.active {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px
}

.rotateOn {
  transform: rotateZ(45deg)
}
span.rotate{
  -moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="main">

        <div class="job 1">
            <h3>
                <a href="#" class="title">Job 1<span class="pull-right plus">+</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-xs pull-right"></a>

            </h3>
            <div class="drop">
                <p class="clearfix">
                    Info
                </p>

                <p><strong>What you’ll do:</strong></p>
                <ul>
                    <li>info</li>


                </ul>

                <p><strong>What we’re looking for:</strong></p>
                <ul>
                    <li>info</li>

                </ul>

                <p><strong>Bonus points:</strong></p>
                <ul>
                    <li>info</li>
                </ul>


            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- //END -->

        <div class="job 2">
            <h3>
                <a href="#" class="title">Job 2<span class="pull-right plus">+</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-xs pull-right"></a>

            </h3>
            <div class="drop">
                <p class="clearfix">
                    Info
                </p>

                <p><strong>What you’ll do:</strong></p>
                <ul>
                    <li>info</li>


                </ul>

                <p><strong>What we’re looking for:</strong></p>
                <ul>
                    <li>info</li>

                </ul>

                <p><strong>Bonus points:</strong></p>
                <ul>
                    <li>info</li>
                </ul>


            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- //END -->

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this fixed my first issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will check this.

Comment: If it works I will accept it. I will check it soon. One question, with your example, I should be able to attach .slideToggle(); on to `$(this).parent().next('.drop').toggleClass('active');` to have it ease in, or will this break the setup?

Comment: I did my best, sorry but it's to late for me. I'm in Italy. Good night.

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE

The OP requested for:

- Remove it's behavior of closing the dropdowns when there's a click anywhere on the doc.
- Rotate the '+' located to the right of title to a 'x'

jsFiddle has been pretty buggy lately, I'm not sure if anyone else has noticed, so I moved this new demo at Plunker.

http://plnkr.co/edit/l9MPtQiafHDUTu8VpgOb?p=preview

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background: #141516;
      font-family: "Source Sans Pro", Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 2.3rem;
      color: #b3b3b3
    }
    ::selection {
      background: #00DE6F;
      color: #141516
    }
    a {
      color: inherit
    }
    a:hover {
      color: inherit
    }
    .container {
      max-width: 500px;
      margin: 0 auto
    }
    .main {
      margin: 0px
    }
    .main a {
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
      transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out
    }
    h3:hover * {
      color: #00DC73
    }
    h3 a:active,
    h3 .plus:active {
      transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    }
    .job {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #191919;
      padding-bottom: 15px
    }
    .job .drop {
      display: none;
      margin-top: 20px
    }
    .job .drop.active {
      display: block;
      margin-top: 20px
    }
    .title {
      position: relative;
    }
    .plus {
      line-height: 16px;
      width: 16px;
      pointer-events: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .rotateOn {
      position: absolute;
      -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
      transform: rotate(-135deg);
      -ms-transform-origin: bottom center;
      -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
      transform-origin: bottom center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <main class="main">
      <section class="job" id="j1">
        <h3 class="title"><a href="#">Job 1</a><span class="plus">+</span></h3>
        <div class="drop">
          <p>Info</p>
          <p><strong>What you’ll do:</strong>
          </p>
          <ul>
            <li>info</li>
          </ul>
          <p><strong>What we’re looking for:</strong>
          </p>
          <ul>
            <li>info</li>
          </ul>
          <p><strong>Bonus points:</strong>
          </p>
          <ul>
            <li>info</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- //END -->

      <section class="job" id="j2">
        <h3 class="title"><a href="#">Job 2</a><span class="plus">+</span></h3>
        <div class="drop">
          <p>Info</p>
          <p><strong>What you’ll do:</strong>
          </p>
          <ul>
            <li>info</li>
          </ul>
          <p><strong>What we’re looking for:</strong>
          </p>
          <ul>
            <li>info</li>
          </ul>
          <p><strong>Bonus points:</strong>
          </p>
          <ul>
            <li>info</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- //END -->
    </main>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('.title').click(function(e) {
      var that = $(this);
      e.preventDefault();
      that.siblings('.drop').toggleClass('active');
      that.children('.plus').toggleClass('rotateOn');
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

You have the `.active` class removed when the whole document is clicked.

https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/duLc8bnm/

Change this:

```
$(function(){
    var title = new DropDown( $('.title'));
    $(document).click(function(){
        $('.drop').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

to this:

```
$(function() {
   var title = new DropDown($('.title'));
   $('.title').click(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
   });
});
```

Comment: This works as well. I'm also trying to figure out the second part of my problem as well. Is it hard to understand? I'm trying to make it as clear as I can :)

Comment: I must've missed your second issue, sorry. What is it? :)

Comment: @EugeneRoss Oh, you want the plus to spin 45 degrees to make a 'x'? Or did you want the title with the plus to rotate? Atm I see the title and plus move 45 degrees one way then back again.

Comment: I basically need it function like this: When a user clicks on either the title or the '+' it functions the same way it does now, but the '+' rotates regardless if the title was clicked, or the '+' was clicked.